# React Native, Redux can't find context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux and trying to grasp the concept of it. I'm receiving the error when redux is looking for context value. I'm sure that I wrapped the whole application in the Provider but still don't understand why it still results in the following error:

**Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider**

This is my themeReducer.js file:

```
const initialState = {
    theme: "dark",
}

const themeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === "changeTheme"){
        if (state.theme === "dark"){
            return {theme: "light"};
        } else {
            return {theme: "dark"}
        }
    }
    return state
}

export default themeReducer
```

This is my index.js for the store:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import themeReducer from './reducers/themeReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    theme: themeReducer
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

export default store
```

Lastly, this is where I wrapped the root component with the provider to access the state:

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import AppNavContainer from "./src/navigations/index";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import store from "./src/store/index"


export default function App() {
  const currentTheme = useSelector(state => state.theme)
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={{ mode: {currentTheme} }}>
        <AppNavContainer />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I'm using the styled component to access the theme value to change the background colour of my custom components. How I understand redux is that if I wrap everything under the Provider, I can access that state anywhere underneath that Provider. Did I do something wrong? Any opinions are appreciated

Comment: Looks like you're calling the useSelector hook inside the App component where the Provider is returned. You can either move the Provider up a component or place the useSelector hook inside of AppNavContainer.

Comment: App.js is outside the provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={{ mode: {currentTheme} }}>
        <AppNavContainer />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
```

The store (and thus `useSelector`) is only available to components that are farther down the component tree from the `Provider`. So in `ThemeProvider`, in `AppNavContainer`, and anything inside `AppNavContainer`. You cannot use `useSelector` in `App`, because there is no `Provider` farther up the tree from `App`.

You'll probably want to split this component into multiple components. For example:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeWrapper />
    </Provider>
  );
}

function ThemeWrapper () {
  const currentTheme = useSelector(state => state.theme)
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={{ mode: {currentTheme} }}>
      <AppNavContainer />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```